# Extract Array of Struct from Parquet into multi-value csv Spark Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, parquet, aws-glue

Using Spark Scala I am trying to extract an array of Struct from parquet. The input is a parquet file. The output is a csv file. The field of the csv can have "multi-values" delimited by "#;". The csv is delimited by ",". What is the best way to accomplish this?

**Schema**

```
root
 |-- llamaEvent: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- activity: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Animal: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- llamaType: string (nullable = true)
```

**Example Input as json (the input will be parquet)**

```
{
   "llamaEvent":{
      "activity":{
         "Animal":[
            {
               "time":"5-1-2020",
               "status":"Running",
               "llamaType":"red llama"
            },
            {
               "time":"6-2-2020",
               "status":"Sitting",
               "llamaType":"blue llama"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Desired CSV Output**

```
time,status,llamaType
5-1-2020#;6-2-2020,running#;sitting,red llama#;blue llama
```

**Update:**
Based on some trial and error, I believe a solution like this maybe appropriate depending on use case. This does a "short cut" by grabbing the array item, cast it to string, then parse out extraneous characters, which is good for some use cases.

```
df.select(col("llamaEvent.activity").getItem("Animal").getItem("time")).cast("String"))
```

Then you can perform whatever parsing you want after such as regexp_replace

```
df.withColumn("time", regexp_replace(col("time"),",",";#"))
```

Several appropriate solutions were also proposed using groupby, explode, aggregate as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to flatten the array of animal attribute `struct`s using SQL function [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#inline) and aggregate the attributes via `collect_list`, followed by concatenating with the specific delimiter.

Given a DataFrame `df` similar to your provided schema, the following transformations will generate the wanted dataset, `dfResult`:

```
val attribCSVs = List("time", "status", "llamaType").map(
    c => concat_ws("#;", collect_list(c)).as(c)
  )

val dfResult = df.
  select($"eventId", expr("inline(llamaEvent.activity.Animal)")).
  groupBy("eventId").agg(attribCSVs.head, attribCSVs.tail: _*)
```

Note that an event identifying column `eventId` is added to the sample json data for the necessary `groupBy` aggregation.

Let's assemble some sample data:

```
val jsons = Seq(
    """{
        "eventId": 1,
        "llamaEvent":{
            "activity":{
                "Animal":[
                    {
                        "time":"5-1-2020",
                        "status":"Running",
                        "llamaType":"red llama"
                    },
                    {
                        "time":"6-2-2020",
                        "status":"Sitting",
                        "llamaType":"blue llama"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }""",
    """{
        "eventId": 2,
        "llamaEvent":{
            "activity":{
                "Animal":[
                    {
                        "time":"5-2-2020",
                        "status":"Running",
                        "llamaType":"red llama"
                    },
                    {
                        "time":"6-3-2020",
                        "status":"Standing",
                        "llamaType":"blue llama"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }"""
)

val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json(jsons.toDS) 

df.show(false)
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|eventId|llamaEvent                                                            |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1      |{{[{red llama, Running, 5-1-2020}, {blue llama, Sitting, 6-2-2020}]}} |
|2      |{{[{red llama, Running, 5-2-2020}, {blue llama, Standing, 6-3-2020}]}}|
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Applying the above transformations, `dfResult` should look like below:

```
dfResult.show(false)
+-------+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|eventId|time              |status           |llamaType            |
+-------+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|1      |5-1-2020#;6-2-2020|Running#;Sitting |red llama#;blue llama|
|2      |5-2-2020#;6-3-2020|Running#;Standing|red llama#;blue llama|
+-------+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Writing `dfResult` to a CSV file:

```
dfResult.write.option("header", true).csv("/path/to/csv")

/*
eventId,time,status,llamaType
1,5-1-2020#;6-2-2020,Running#;Sitting,red llama#;blue llama
2,5-2-2020#;6-3-2020,Running#;Standing,red llama#;blue llama
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be a working solution for you

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(str([a_json]))],T.StringType())

df = df.withColumn('col', F.from_json("value", T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
df = df.withColumn("col", F.explode("col"))


df = df.withColumn("col", F.from_json("col", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
df = df.withColumn("llamaEvent", df.col.getItem("llamaEvent"))

df = df.withColumn("llamaEvent", F.from_json("llamaEvent", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
df = df.select("*", F.explode("llamaEvent").alias("x","y"))

df = df.withColumn("Activity", F.from_json("y", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
df = df.select("*", F.explode("Activity").alias("x","yy"))

df = df.withColumn("final_col", F.from_json("yy", T.ArrayType(T.StringType())))
df = df.withColumn("final_col", F.explode("final_col"))
df = df.withColumn("final_col", F.from_json("final_col", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.StringType())))
df = df.withColumn("time", df.final_col.getItem("time")).withColumn("status", df.final_col.getItem("status")).withColumn("llamaType", df.final_col.getItem("llamaType")).withColumn("agg_col", F.lit("1"))

df_grp = df.groupby("agg_col").agg(F.concat_ws("#;", F.collect_list(df.time)).alias("time"), F.concat_ws("#;", F.collect_list(df.status)).alias("status"), F.concat_ws("#;", F.collect_list(df.llamaType)).alias("llamaType"))


display(df)
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+
|               value|                 col|          llamaEvent|       x|                   y|            Activity|     x|                  yy|           final_col|    time| status| llamaType|agg_col|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+
|[{'llamaEvent': {...|[llamaEvent -> {"...|[activity -> {"An...|activity|{"Animal":[{"time...|[Animal -> [{"tim...|Animal|[{"time":"5-1-202...|[time -> 5-1-2020...|5-1-2020|Running| red llama|      1|
|[{'llamaEvent': {...|[llamaEvent -> {"...|[activity -> {"An...|activity|{"Animal":[{"time...|[Animal -> [{"tim...|Animal|[{"time":"5-1-202...|[time -> 6-2-2020...|6-2-2020|Sitting|blue llama|      1|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+
df_grp.show(truncate=False)
+-------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
|agg_col|time              |status          |llamaType            |
+-------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
|1      |5-1-2020#;6-2-2020|Running#;Sitting|red llama#;blue llama|
+-------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```